# How do you reference an Empty set ({}) valued field in mongodb through php?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have the following code which works fine in my mongodb client:-

```
 db.whatevercollection.update({id:999999,external_ids:{}},
    {$unset: { "external_ids": true}})
```

How do I reference this empty set in php so that the external_ids field is completely removed? Using this:-

```
array('id' =>  $id,'external_ids'=>array())
```

Doesn't work...

Comment: what first code is doing can you explain? and what expected outcome you want in php

Comment: I would like the external_id field to be completely removed, which works fine through the client. However through php the field remains untouched, i.e. "external_ids" : {}

Comment: Superb - Thanks Neil Lunn! First link was perfect:-
json_decode ('{}') did the trick! Thanks guys...